# Async callback failing when page is posted back at the same time

Tags: .net, asynchronous, postback, webmethod, pagemethods

I am facing problem with js async callback in my solution. Here is the req ;

1. User clicks on 'Generate Excel' button.
2. On server excel file is being generated with large amount of data (takes about 2 mins).
3. During this time the user can do other operations in the application , including page postbacks/requests/etc.
4. When the excel is generated user is provided a popup to download the file from server irrespective of the page the user is on.

What I did :

- Created a function which generates the excel file w.r.t business need '**GenerateReport**'. (Server side)
- Wrote one WebMethod '**GetFilePath**' which recursively checks if the file has been generated by **GenerateReport** method on some server location and returns the file path of the new file, this method never returns the same file path again according to business logic. (Server side)
- Created one javascript function **DownloadLink()** which recursively calls the **GetFilePath** method with delay of 60 seconds. Function call looks like this :

  PageMethods.GetFilePath(UserId, onSuccess, onError);
- OnSuccess and OnError are JS callback functions, OnSuccess is fired when URL for download of file is available, this JS method displays popup for download, OnError is called in case of any error.

Works fine, until following scenario happens. 
**When OnSuccesss is called from GetFilePath method and postback for some other operation happens at the same time** , the OnSuccess call never gets made as new page has not yet been loaded and download popup is not shown to the user.

What should I do to solve this problem so that its ensured that user gets the download link.

Comment: 1.get user email address and send mail with file path its a best solution. 2.check on every page load is download file is created or not if file is available then generate link

Comment: @AnantDabhi , The requirement is that a file save popup should be displayed whenever the file is generated on the server , irrespective of the page the user is on, in the application. Can not depend on page load because it will need some kind of postback. Email would be easy but its not my call :(.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there is a download link ready when the page is initially loaded in addition to the check every 60 seconds.

Comment: The Webmethod **GetFilePath** gets the correct file from the server folder and appends '_downloaded' to the file name before sending it, for example 1.xls will become 1_downloaded.xls. This ensures that some already sent link is not sent again to user each time from that method. Once renamed and with the problem mentioned in the OP of Onsuccess not being called, the same link is never sent back to user and user never gets the link again. Using PageLoad will also not solve the problem as the file was already renamed on the server.

Comment: Maybe you need to use state between pages like session.

Comment: Is there an entirely different and better way of achieving similar result ?